# Migration not listed by .net core CLI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble updating database from .net core CLI

I have 2 solutions, one that has the connection string in the startup (firstSolution) and another that has the migrations folder and DataContext (secondSolution)

I used this to add migration and I am currently in the secondSolution directory

```
dotnet ef migrations add migration-name -s ../firstSolution/firstSolution.csproj
```

and then I tried updating the database like this

```
dotnet ef database update
```

But then it made this error

```
Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

so I added the --startup-project (-s) to be able to see the connection string and ran the same command like this:

`dotnet ef database update -s ../firstSolution/firstSolution.csproj`

it returns this

```
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
```

I tried listing the migrations using:

```
dotnet ef mifrations list
```

so the same error again

```
Unable to create an object of type 'DataContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

so I edited the command to this:

```
dotnet ef migrations list -s  ../firstSolution/firstSolution.csproj
```

And my new migration wasn't listed in there
So I tried adding the second solution that has the migrations in the startup of the first like this

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.MigrationsAssembly("seconsSolution"))
            , ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

But it also didn't include my migration

Can someone help me how to access the migration in the secondSolution so I can update the database?

I am using VSCode, .net core 3.1 and ef core 3.1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the .csproj didn't include the migration files
once I added them in the secondSolution.csproj it was able to update the database. However I am not sure why it didn't include them in the first place.

```
<Compile Include="Migrations\migrationName.cs" />
<Compile Include="Migrations\migrationName.Designer.cs" />
```

Comment: I also had the same issue! Thanks for figuring this out.  I really wonder what could be the source of this.  Do you think it's a bug in the CLI ?